# Configuring an ImageView within a Callback from another ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, picasso

I need to configure `ImageView` (imageBackground) with the `ImagePrincipal` Bitmap, but the error (`NullPointerException`) occurs when passing the Bitmap to the `imageBackground`

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(final ViewGroup container, final int position) {
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.slider_image_perfil_adapter, null);
    // final ProgressBar progressBar =  (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    final ImageView imagePrincipal = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagePrincipal);
    final ImageView imageBackground = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagebackground);

    pager.addView(view);
    if (!images.get(position).getUrl().equals("")) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(images.get(position).getUrl()).fit().centerInside().into(imagePrincipal, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                try {
                    if (imagePrincipal.getDrawable() != null) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imagePrincipal.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                        imagePrincipal.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                        if (!isExibicaoPortifolioActivity) {
                            bitmap = criarEfeitoBlur(bitmap, 25.0 f);
                            if (bitmap != null) {
                                //Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(imagePrincipal.getContext().getResources(), bitmap);
                                //imagePrincipal.setBackground(drawable);

                                imageBackground.setImageBitmap(bitmap); //This erro ocurred in this line 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Log.e("Picasso", "onError: ");
            }
        });
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: add stacktrace.

Comment: Make sure id of imageBackground is correct and it exist in slider_image_perfil_adapter layout.

Comment: Thanks Rasi, actually the error was in the Imageview ID. My mistake ;)

Comment: What was the error

Comment: I wrote R.id.imagebackground with the "b" lowercase and in the xml was uppercase

Comment: I transformed my comment into answer. Accept it if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NullPointerException` while setting Bitmap in `ImageView`. According to your code, you checked for `Bitmap` is null or not. So suspect is your `ImageView` is null.

Make sure id of `imageBackground` is correct and it exist in `slider_image_perfil_adapter` layout.